# How can you receive the most recent permalink or terms of the newly saved post?

Tags: permalinks, terms, block-editor, save-post, bug

When using the Gutenberg Block Editor the normal hooks for saving a post don't have the same behavior as with the classic editor.

- [`pre_post_update`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_post_update/)
- [`save_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/)
- [`wp_insert_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post/)

For example, if you hook into the `save_post`-hook the `$permalink` and the `$categories` will ***not*** return the new value, but instead the old value. Which is not the behavior that I expected from the classic editor.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'custom_save_post', 10, 3 );

function custom_save_post( $post_id, $post, $update ) 
{
  $permalink = get_permalink( $post_id ); 
  $categories = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'category' );
}
```

How can I make it work so that I can retrieve the pre-updated permalink and the post-updated permalink?

Comment: I can only tell you that all my test text files contain the proper contents - the correct/updated permalink in `permalink.txt` and the correct/updated category objects dump in `categories.txt` and `terms.txt`. So I didn't need to proceed to the fourth step (editing the core `taxonomy.php` file). Are you using the latest WordPress stable release? Have you tested on other hosts? This might be something specific to your host/server..

Comment: @SallyCJ I really appreciate you taking the time to test. Thanks for your comments. It's weird because it happend on my local computer but also on two different remote hosts. But it helps a lot that you did not notice anything, perhaps I should try a different computer.

Comment: Ok, but I should mention that I tested only with the block editor enabled (i.e. not tested on the classic editor) and if you haven't, try testing the Quick Edit link on the Posts -> All Posts page.

Comment: I am also using the block editor. Great tip about the Quick Edit link. The problem does not occur there. Could you confirm one more thing. If you edit the post the "Update" button will become clickable again after some duration right? Because mine is stuck even on fresh host, fresh wordpress, default theme. When it's stuck the bug appears on the full post (not the quick edit).

Comment: So I kinda did expect you'd ask that question, and the answer is, the button works just fine for me - no "stuck-ing". So try to inspect the network - on Chrome, `Ctrl + Shift + I` then go to the Network tab and just check the relevant requests. In fact, the console might be able to tell you what's going on with the button getting stuck..

Comment: I did use the inspector. Nothing out of the ordinary, not an error or anything. I tried different browsers with no success. I am now trying to create a new hosting on Combell with a new database and the setting to automatically install WordPress from their repository. See if that makes any difference. At least from your comments I know it should work, so it must be my system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105014/discussion-between-mark-and-sally-cj).

Comment: you could try changing the priority from `10` to `11` to make sure you are running your code after the default `save_post` action.

Comment: I tried 1, 11 and 99 as priorites that didn't change anything.

Comment: To other readers, everything I said was correct, except that I wasn't aware I actually had the default Custom Fields editor enabled - that editor is in a metabox. I also forgot that the default behavior of the "Update" button (on the block editor mode) is that the button is disabled until you made a change to the post (e.g. added a category). Sorry about that.. :)

Answer (score 3):

When using the Gutenberg Block editor you need to use different hooks to get the expected behavior.

- [`rest_insert_{$this->post_type}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_insert_this-post_type/) The pre-update hook.
- [`rest_after_insert_{$this->post_type}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_after_insert_this-post_type/) The post-update hook.

*credits: @SallyCJ*

Comment: Issue reported on Gutenberg Github (https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/20550)

Comment: I tested on a fresh WordPress install with no plugins and using the default theme and with the default Custom Fields editor being *disabled*, and I actually got the same results as originally mentioned in the question (old permalink & categories) when using the `save_post` hook. So I'm not sure if that's really a bug (but surely the WordPress core should have/give a reasonable explanation for that), but if you use the [`rest_after_insert_<post type>` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_after_insert_this-post_type/), you'd get the proper permalink & categories. +1, btw :)

Comment: So I think I may know why the `save_post` hook is giving the old permalink and categories - If you look at [`WP_REST_Posts_Controller::update_item()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_posts_controller/update_item/), the function calls `wp_update_post()` which then calls `wp_insert_post()` which fires hooks like `save_post` and `wp_insert_post`, but that `update_item()` only updates the categories/terms *after* `wp_update_post()` is called, hence for permalinks that rely upon the categories, the permalink would only be updated after the categories are updated.

Comment: Having said that, it's *probably* not a bug.. but we just have to use another hook for post being *created or updated via the REST API*. But even if so, the WordPress core should mention that somewhere... :)

Comment: I still believe if something does not behave as is expected it can be considered a bug. I take the classic editor and documentation as the origin. Gutenberg which does fire the same hooks, should also use it in the same way and not a different way 'cause that is the confusion we have right now. Different entry points, different results. Anyway I can finally continue with the project =)

Comment: Understood and I'll keep an eye on the GitHub [issue](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/20550) :) And good luck with that project!